# Overlay click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, openlayers-3

How to add click event to `ol.Overlay` ?

`map.forEachLayerAtPixel(...)` saying is not a function

`map.forEachFeatureAtPixel()` also doesn't work becouse i dont have feature in this overlay.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'overlay-div';
var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
    position: ol.proj.fromLonLat(lon, lat),
    positioning: 'center-center',
    element: div 
});
map.addOverlay(overlay );
```

Comment: The same advice, as always, you have to show some code, some progress work, furthermore, a search is the first step before a post. Similar question ... http://stackoverflow.com/q/30657876/4640499

Comment: I added simple code, i just wanted to know if is native event for Overlay in OL3.

Comment: @JonatasWalker OL3 is quite something in itself, asking more code from OP is like asking someone to show you jQuery's source code snippets.

Comment: @Sko Did you see your answer at the link posted?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event using jQuery. For example, add the following after your code:

```
$(div).click(function () {
    console.log(overlay);
});
```